# How can I embed a jwplayer so it plays inline in a facebook stream?

Tags: facebook, video, stream, inline, jwplayer

I have a custom skin on my jwplayer and I'm trying to get it to play inline in the facebook stream, like the youtube player. I've spent two days looking at docs and tweaking code for this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's an example of my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Contour"/> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="188896031148408"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.contour.com/stories/jimmy-the-greek-board-view-of-summer-x-park-course"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Jimmy the Greek board view of Summer X park course"/> 
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.contour.com/flash/jwplayer.swf?playlistfile=/stories/39073.xml&skin=/flash/jwskin.zip&repeat=list&autostart=true"/> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.amazonaws.com/contour.staging/images/assets/12133/quarter/F71C41BCA5B9825898ECBC56151E8BB820100905-94257-1dzxruc-0.jpg"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Jimmy the Greek Marcus was kind enough to bust out a few warm up laps with a boardcam mount. This years setup was primarily cement with some skatelite features around the perimeter. Thanks man, you killed it on Sunday"/>
```

The facebook url linter shows that it's picking up the info. There's even a 'video' heading that says "Status: Video embedding on Facebook enabled". Yet, it doesn't work.

I've tried using 'video' and 'swf' as the og:type. I've tried specifying the video height/width.  I've tried using different video types.  When I load the og:video url in a browser I get a swf that autoplays my video.

Right now, the thumbnail that appears in the facebook stream does NOT link to the video's page as it normally would, which I take as a sign that I'm on the right track.  However, it also does not play a video :) The little blue play button also does not show up on my thumbnail.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.

LongTail wrote a a helpful blog post on the topic: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player

That's what made me realize that I always browse facebook over SSL but my player was being served over plain HTTP. Switching my facebook to plain HTTP solved the problem. Now I need to go through my stack and convert everything to https so this will work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jwplayer swf object to play directly your youtube video
You should encode your param with URL-ENCODE method. Like that:

```
http://yoursite.com/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DB-YRHQN5e9Q&image=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FB-YRHQN5e9Q%2Fhqdefault.jpg&autostart=true
```

Answer (score -1):

I haved the same problem, but I solved this.
I have no idea which tag solve my problem, but when my code is looks like this, jw player 5.1 pro is working on facebook:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/embeds/jwplayer5/swfobject.js"></script>
 <meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Big Buck Bunny" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000446876505">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="257720611082074">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://zobolio.com/embeds/posters/ezekiel.png" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://zobolio.com/embeds/jwplayer/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zobolio.com/embeds/ezekiel.mp4&autostart=true" /> 
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://zobolio.com/embeds/jwplayer5/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zobolio.com/embeds/ezekiel.mp4&autostart=true" />
```

Comment: When posting an answer to a question please make sure that you understand both the problem and your solution. If you aren't sure as to the why your solution works that's okay but posting an answer and saying "I don't know what part of this makes it work" does not make for a good question. Do some experimentation and find out which tag exactly it is. If you find out what tag, but don't know why the tag fixes it, that's not as bad as not knowing at all.

Comment: But if you replace this tags , the player is working, so I fixed your problem, right?

Comment: It's not my problem, and it's not helpful to other people who happen across this question. Do some research so you know why it fixed it, maybe your fix doesn't quite do the good things you think it might it do. Improve your answer to help the person who asked the question and any future readers.